# VS Solution Debug Source Files Setting Location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

On the VS solution properties under:

- Common Properties

  - Debug Source Files

There is a box entitled "Directories Containing source code" -- where is this configuration item stored? I can't seem to find documentation for it on Microsoft's website. The settings don't seem to be stored directly in the *.sln file either, as modifying this box and saving the solution seems to have no effect on the *.sln (no change in size, last write time, etc).

The setting is persisted somewhere because if you close and reopen VS the entries from the prior execution remain. But where is it stored? I can't find it anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are saved into a hidden binary file located at `.vs` directory. It's the solution user options file with `.suo` extension which contains per-user solution options. There is also other stuff in there apart from those paths.

The file is vaguely documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-user-options-dot-suo-file?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks. I thought  I checked the *.suo. Guess not. Oops.